# Is my interpretation of the word 'first' in §3.3.2/6 correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In the snippet below I can understand (from §3.3.2/6 second bullet point) that the name `B` in the declaration `struct B* p;` is injected into the global namespace as a *class-name*.

```
struct A {
 //   struct B{};
    int B;
    struct B* p;
};

void f(B&) {}

int main()
{
    A a;
    f(*a.p);
}
```

§3.3.2/6:

> The point of declaration of a class **first** declared in an
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> - for a declaration of the form
>
>   *class-key* *attribute-specifier-seq* *opt* *identifier*;
>
>   the *identifier* is declared to be a *class-name* in the scope that
>     contains the declaration, otherwise
> - for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
>   *class-key* *identifier*
>
>   if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope, the *identifier* is declared as a
>     *class-name* in the namespace that contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a *friend* declaration, the *identifier* is
>     declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the
>     declaration. [ *Note*: These rules also apply within templates. — *end
>     note* ] [ *Note*: Other forms of *elaborated-type-specifier* do not
>     declare a new name, and therefore must refer to an existing type-name.
>     See 3.4.4 and 7.1.6.3. — *end note* ]

However if I uncomment the definition of `struct B{};` inside `struct A`, what I said earlier with regard to the injection of name `B` into the global namespace, doesn't occur anymore, as the code doesn't compile. I believe this has to do with the word **first** (emphasis mine) above, since now the *class-name* `B`, in the declaration `struct B* p;` is no more its first declaration **in its declarative region**. Am I correct saying this?

Assuming my interpretation is correct, why is it that the *class-name* `B` is not injected in the global namespace in this case? Note that the nested class `struct B{};` will be hidden inside A in this case, i.e., even if we change the declaration of function `f` to `void f(A::B&)` the code won't compile.

There is still one other point that isn't clear to me: what made the implementers to decide for the class-name injection into the namespace, or block scope, containing the elaborated-type-specifier, in the second bullet point above? That is, why didn't they leave the class-name declaration inside the class scope?

Comment: The injection to the enclosing namespace is certainly for compatibility with C.

Comment: Could you explore this a bit more?

Comment: C does not have class/struct scope, therefore, `struct S { struct X { int y; }; int x; }; struct X my_var = {42};` is legal in C (uh, it's ugly -- but it actually compiles with clang and gcc, albeit with a warning in the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, that *first* keyword in §3.3.2/6 is also the reason for the following:

```
struct A {
    struct B *p;
    struct B{};
    int b;
};

void f(B* arg) {
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(arg), A::B*>::value; // not the same type
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    f(a.p);
}
```

> why is it that the class-name B is not injected in the global namespace in this case?

As dyp pointed out, [basic.lookup.elab]/2 explains that 3.3.2 is only carried out in case **no previous declaration could be found**

> If the elaborated-type-specifier is introduced by the class-key and
>   this lookup does not find a previously declared type-name, or if the
>   elaborated-type-specifier appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;
>
> elaborated-type-specifier is a declaration that introduces the
>   class-name as described in 3.3.2.the

Finally I tracked down this behavior to possibly be an inheritance from C99 6.7.2.3/p8

> If a type specifier of the form
>
> struct-or-union identifier
>
> occurs
>   other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other declaration
>   of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an incomplete
>   structure or union type, and declares the identifier as the tag of
>   that type.113)
>
> 113) A similar construction with enum does not exist.

Comment: Very good answer, but I believe that the example given by @dyp above is more illustrative of the alluded compatibility with C in regard to the class-name injection proposed in the second bullet point of 3.3.2/6 (+1).

Answer (score 0):

I would say your interpretation is correct. When you uncomment `struct B{};`, the `struct B* p;` line will simply refer to that struct `A::B`.

To answer your question why, when you leave `struct B {};` commented out, the name `struct B` is inserted into the global scope. I would say that's because the authors didn't want you to (somewhat) silently declare `B` as a member of `A` without using a *member-specification* for the name `B`.